# How can I pass a Jenkins parameter escaped to Fabric?

Tags: shell, jenkins, fabric

I have a Jenkins build job that has a text parameter. That parameter is a URL and I need to pass it to Fabric. If the URL contains a "=" then Fabric blows up.

Example parameter value LOGOURL: http://example.com/test.jpg?foo=bar

My execute shell command:

```
fab -f create-demo.py main:sitename="$SITENAME",domainname=$DOMAINNAME,logourl="$LOGOURL",bgurl="$BGURL",host=test.example.com
```

Error in Jenkins:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 700, in main
    commands_to_run = parse_arguments(arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 536, in parse_arguments
    k, v = result
ValueError: too many values to unpack
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

How do I pass through the LOGOURL parameter correctly so that Fabric does not die?

Answer (score 2):

[Equals signs can be escaped with backslashes](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments) in Fabric.  So try setting LOGOURL to  `http://example.com/test.jpg?foo\=bar`instead.

If you can't change the value of LOGOURL, then you can try using the shell to escape the `=` for you:

```
fab -f create-demo.py main:sitename="$SITENAME",domainname=$DOMAINNAME,logourl=${LOGOURL/=/\\=},bgurl="$BGURL",host=test.example.com
```

Comment: no the escaping does not work: `/tmp/hudson1651138574766027790.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson1651138574766027790.sh: Bad substitution`

Comment: Try out using `foo\\=bar`, `foo\\\=bar`, and `foo\\\\=bar` in your URL instead of `foo\=bar`.  Could be some double escaping going on.

Comment: I can't add \\ into the URL because is is user provided in a Jenkins input field. So I need a way to make it valid later.